# primefaces datagrid does not work when rows and columns are defined

Tags: jsf, datagrid, primefaces, carousel

I want to represent my data from a MYSQL database table in a primefaces carousel or slider or datagrid with one row. The carousel does not work at all. The datagrid does not work when I add rows="1" attribute and I don't know how to implement my data into a slider.
Any ideas?

Comment: The [`<p:carousel>` demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/carousel.jsf) looks very straightforward in order to use the component. Why would you say it doesn't suit your needs? Just make sure your managed bean has at least `@ViewScoped` or wider and you're retrieving the `List<YourData>`in the @PostConstruct` method of your managed bean and not in the getter method.

Comment: Yes @LuiggiMendoza 'code'<p:carousel> is very suitable for my case, I was not able to get it to work. And it seems that what I am missing is preloading data via a 'code'@PostConstruct method. My managed bean is in 'code'@SessionView and I use a DataModel to retrieve my items. I need to use 'code'@PostConstruct. I'll update after I've done my homework. Thanks.

Comment: I represent my code for controller getItems method and my carousel, that doesn't show anything:`public DataModel getItems() {
        if (items == null) {
            items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
        }
        return items;        
    }` and my carousel: `<p:carousel id="tours-carousel" var="item" value="#{tourController.items}" rows="1">` I used `@PostConstruct` with `items=getPagination.createPageDataModel();` and it doesn't work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza And I noticed I have a javax.faces.model.NoRowException and data cannot be populated in a dataTable either.

Comment: So I found out that my carousel dose not work with the javascript I have in the header of my document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The version of jQuery I had included into my xhtml file was different from that of primefaces jQuery library. So I just used the primefaces jQuery library and deleted the other one and all primefaces components worked as they should.